# Redirect direct access to images to its post page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect images from WordPress.

If someones goes to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/sample-image.jpg
```

I would like them to be redirected to the post URL at:

```
http://www.mysite.com/sample-image
```

1. yes the image and URL have the same name.
2. the year and the month change.
3. sometimes the files are `jpg`, `gif`, `png`, etc.